# Session timeout issue while making payment using PayPal sandbox account

Tags: c#, .net, rest, paypal-sandbox

Getting this webpage when trying to make a payment:

> You've been inactive for a while, so we logged you out to protect your account. Return to the merchant and restart the payment process.

I'm getting a url for this website as https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutweb/genericError?code=SU5WQUxJRF9SRVNPVVJDRV9JRA%3D%3D&cancelLink=&merchantName=

But I have not been inactive and there is no reason for PayPal to log me out
[Timed out Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7LTe.png)

1. Check Session Duration: I'm not taking an unusually long time between actions during the payment process.
2. Cookies and Cache: Clear my browser's cookies and cache, and then tried the payment process again.
3. Browser Compatibility: Updated chrome to latest version.
4. Network Issues: None such, strong reliable network.
5. Test with Different Accounts: Tried using different sandbox accounts (both personal) to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is no code in the posted question.